# Reshape dataframe and create similarity matrix

Tags: r

I have a data table, and I try Reshaping it but it doesn't work, how do I do this:

I have a data table:

```
Name | Value
-------------
Bob  | 8,9,10
------------
Mike | 2,3,4
------------
Sandr| 5,6,7
```

How do I make this into a list like:

```
Value | Name
-------------
  2   | Mike
  3   | Mike
  4   | Mike
  5   | Sandr
  6   | Sandr
  7   | Sandr
  8   | Bob
  9   | Bob
  10  | Bob
```

And then make this list into a matrix like:

```
    2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
   -------------------
2 | 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
3 | 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 | 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 | 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
6 | 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
7 | 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
8 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
9 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
10| 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

Comment: R data objects do not have those separators. So is it really a data.table (which is the specific name of a special type of object) or is it a dataframe or is it just a text file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functions you are looking for are `stack` and `contrasts`.

```
data<-list(bob=c(8,9,10),mike=c(2,3,4),sandr=c(5,6,7))

as.data.frame(data)
```

```
  bob mike sandr
1   8    2     5
2   9    3     6
3  10    4     7
```

```
stack(data)
```

```
  values   ind
1      8   bob
2      9   bob
3     10   bob
4      2  mike
5      3  mike
6      4  mike
7      5 sandr
8      6 sandr
9      7 sandr
```

```
df<-stack(data)
contrasts(df$ind,contrasts=FALSE)[df$ind,df$ind]
```

```
      bob bob bob mike mike mike sandr sandr sandr
bob     1   1   1    0    0    0     0     0     0
bob     1   1   1    0    0    0     0     0     0
bob     1   1   1    0    0    0     0     0     0
mike    0   0   0    1    1    1     0     0     0
mike    0   0   0    1    1    1     0     0     0
mike    0   0   0    1    1    1     0     0     0
sandr   0   0   0    0    0    0     1     1     1
sandr   0   0   0    0    0    0     1     1     1
sandr   0   0   0    0    0    0     1     1     1
```

You can assign row names and column names and sort if desired

```
im<-contrasts(df$ind,contrasts=FALSE)[df$ind,df$ind] 
rownames(im)<-df$values
colnames(im)<-df$values
```

Comment: Okay, but say I had like a 1000 rows and each name had 100 values. How would I go about that? I could not list every row and every value in the column

Comment: @SanthoshSubramanian The same exact code works with a data frame. That was just me inputting your sample data.

Comment: data<-list(bob=c(8,9,10),mike=c(2,3,4),sandr=c(5,6,7))

as.data.frame(data) What is the point of this step. When I do data <- list(dataframe), then as.data.frame(dataframe), I am getting the same thing

Comment: When I write the list function as list(bob=c(8,9,10),mike=c(2,3,4),sandr=c(5,6,7)) , it works, not when I do list(dataframe). I have to much data to type every every value for every name.

Comment: @SanthoshSubramanian If your data is in a data frame then just `stack` it directly. Do not wrap your data frame in a list.

Comment: You may consider the example to be `data<-data.frame(bob=c(8,9,10),mike=c(2,3,4),sandr=c(5,6,7))` instead. Skip the `as.data.frame` and proceed.

Comment: data <- stack(df)
Error in stack.data.frame(df) : no vector columns were selected.

Answer (score 1):

```
 res <- read.table(text="Name | Value
 Bob  | 8,9,10
 Mike | 2,3,4
 Sandr| 5,6,7", header=TRUE, sep="|")
dres <- data.frame(Value= unlist( strsplit(as.character(res$Value), ",") )
, Name=rep(res$Name, each=3))
dres <- dres[order(as.numeric(as.character(dres$Value))), ]
dres
outer(sort(dres$Value), sort(dres$Value), FUN=function(x,y) dres[x, "Name"] == dres[y,"Name"] )
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]
 [1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [2,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```